# Storing a value from a complex type in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a Language class in my domain model which represents a user language. This is not persisted to the database as this is known internally, and defined within the application.

My class is like this:

```
public class User {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    /* snip */
    public Language Language { get; set; }

}
```

Language has a key value of 'code' which is something like en/fr/de/etc. I'd like to have EF store only the language code. How can I do this, without changing the domain model to have a language code.

Comment: The Language must be persisted somewhere so I guess it is hard coded from what you said. In which case could you not just add a LanguageCode property to your User entity and then use the Lanuguage property to return the Language which has a matching LanguageCode.

Comment: @DaveWilliams I thought about that, but I don't want to pollute my domain model :)